# A philosophical question about amps

Tags: power-supply, amperage

I'm flipping out because I cannot find the answer to this anywhere.  It's wholly philosophical.  In reference to the amps of power supplies/adapters:

**If all that matters is that enough amps are supplied, why aren't all power supplies/adapters just built with something like 100 amps or maybe 10 amps?**

- Why have us running around wondering: "Does this supply enough amps?"?
- Why do they not all just supply plenty

Comment: Here's the first 12V 100A supply I found, do you want to use something this size/cost to charge your phone or run your portable radio: http://www.ebay.com/itm/100-AMP-CONTINUOUS-POWER-SUPPLY-12-Volt-POWER-YOUR-LINEAR-AMPLIFIER-CB-RADIO-dc-/131177533516

Comment: To use the water analogy, why aren't all garden hoses the size of firehoses?

Comment: A cheap 5V 1A USB supply can rarely supply its 1A without overheating and losing regulation.. imagine building everything with.. 10, 100x times the necessary overhead..

Comment: I do not think that your question has a philosophical background. It is simply a question to find the best trade-off between (necessary) performance and other important quantities like weight, cost, volume, reliability, ... Remember: Any technical device should not be as "good" as possible (that`s impossible!) but as "good" as necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building excess capcity makes the device larger, heavier, and most importantly **more expensive**

it's not that an overpowered power supply can't run a low powered device, it's just that a correctly sized power supply is usually better suited.

sure you can charge a phone from a 5000A capable 5V supply, but finding an outlet to plug it in is tricky and the wheelbarrow to transport it is inconvenient,  much better is a pocket sized 2A charger....

Comment: Also a 5000A capable supply would cause you a lot of trouble if you accidentally shorted the output

Comment: I'd like to see someone hook up a 5000A 5V supply to get at least 4.5V into a device using 5000A.

Comment: I'd like to own a 5000 amp 5 volt supply. For... reasons.

Comment: 5 V / 5000A = 1mOhm. You'd need some pretty good wires in order to deliver this kind of parameters.

Comment: Also, 5 V * 5000 A = 5 kW. Good luck keeping this kind of waste heat away from your superconducting power supply wires or else they won't be superconducting for long.

Comment: @SeanBoddy it's not as crazy as it sounds if you want to do a bit of electrochemistry: extract aluminium, sodium or potassium from their ores at home? (OK that is crazy!) But a large electroplating bath is going to need exactly that kind of current / voltage.

Comment: @JanDvorak, actually, power transmission grade circuit breakers and lines typically test in the 2-digit micro ohms range. If I were gifted this power supply I would have to sell it because I couldn't afford the gear that I would need to make it do anything cool. If I could I'd be electrolysing and electroplating my little heart out. And actually it would be 25 kilowatts, not 5.

Comment: @steveverrill, actually if I had that kind of capacity I think the very first thing I would work on would be an arc furnace. Gonna need a lot of steel and aluminum for the other stupid things I'd like to try, and it would be nice to get some of it as scrap, or billet.

Comment: Alright I see...One of those common sensical, right-under-my-nose type things lol.  Thanks for the responses

Comment: @steveverrill  electronics and chemistry are two of my favorite hobbies...Maybe electrochemistry is the next logical evolution lol